# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oidcController' defined in file [H:\Documents\sc-sse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I imported a maven project into my eclipse whenever I run the application then getting the below error --

[image]

[image]
I tried to add @component and @service annoation but still getting same issue.

Below find find code -

```java
package com.thehecklers.ssecoidc;
    
import java.util.Map;
    
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SsecOidcApplication {

    @Bean
    WebClient client(ClientRegistrationRepository regRepo, OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository cliRepo) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction fFunc = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
    regRepo, cliRepo);
    
        fFunc.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
    
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8081/resources").apply(fFunc.oauth2Configuration())
    .build();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsecOidcApplication.class, args);
    }
    
}
    
@RestController
class OidcController {
    
    private final WebClient client;
    
    public OidcController(WebClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    String hello() {
        return "Bonjour Montreal!";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/something")
    String getSomethingFromRServer() {
        return client.get().uri("/something").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/claims")
    Map getClaimsFromRServer() {
        return client.get().uri("/claims").retrieve().bodyToMono(Map.class).block();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/email")
    String getSubjectFromRServer() {
        return client.get().uri("/email").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
    }
}
```

[image]

IN properties.yml below code ava

spring:
security:
oauth2:
client:
registration:
google:
client-id: <insert_client_id_here>
client-secret: <insert_client_id_here>
okta:
client-id: 0oa57d0tayWiRDK145d7
client-secret: snHEEz214GeRn9VUl68eizZoMmlEEyPHDj9dQ0QW
provider:
okta:
issuer-uri: https://dev-82991527.okta.com/oauth2/default

Please provide any solution-

Comment: Hi, can you please add your code as code and not photos.

Comment: code are added in text form